# session storage listener works only on manual change

Tags: reactjs

I have an application, where I want to store a bool-value in sessionstorage  that tells, if a user is logged in. This boolean shall be listened to and whenever it changes, the state in the app-component shall change to the value of the sessionstorage variable.

To accomplish this task, I added a window event listener, that should track the updates of sessionstorage and then change the state. This didn't work via storage.setItem(). BUT it worked, when I changed the value in local storage via the developer tools of chrome. This means, that somehow the listening works.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      let isTrue = (sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === 'true');
      this.setState({loggedIn: isTrue});
      window.addEventListener('storage', this.sessionStorageUpdated)
    }
  }

  sessionStorageUpdated() {
    console.log("storage updated");
    let isTrue = (sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn') === 'true');
    console.log(isTrue);
    if (isTrue) {
      this.setState({loggedIn: true})
    } 
    else {
      this.setState({loggedIn: false})
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', this.sessionStorageUpdated)
    }
  }
```

I expect that the state changes if the sessionstorage is updated, but this doesn't happen. It does however work, if I change the value in the dev tools directly.

Comment: Note: The storage event is only triggered when a window other than itself makes the changes.

Comment: okay, but how can I work around that? I could reload the page everytime I change the session storage, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to handle it.

Comment: you could keep the `loggedIn` state in context and then update the context when authentication status changes

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thank you for your support! Now I change the loggedIn attribute via states and use the sessionstorage only to keep the loggedIn state up in case of page reload.